# How do I dynamically change less variables in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, less

I have the Less package loaded in my Meteor application and it is working fine. Now I need to allow the users of my app. to override my less variables. I have looked at :

```
less.modifyVars({
    '@canvas': '#5B83AD'
});
```

but my app. is saying that 'less is not defined'. Can someone suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less files can only be modified up to the point they're compiled to css files. This happens when you deploy your Meteor app.

It's not possible to change less variables at runtime. You would have to manipulate the DOM instead. Jquery is able to do this by targeting the DOM elements you want to change. You would have to tag them with a class.

An approach this way make work for you:

```
<div class="canvas"></div>
```

Then you could edit it at runtime using Jquery:

```
$(".canvas").css({background: '#5B83AD'});
```

Edit: I think the code you're refering to is the `less.js` client side file from https://github.com/less/less.js/. There's a bit more info under 'Client side usage' on http://lesscss.org/

This is a bit different from the Meteor `less` package, which is exclusively a server side compiler during development.

If you downloaded the `less.js` file (from https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip) and placed it in your `/client/compatiblity` folder you could use it in the way you wish. Keep in mind you may have to remove the Meteor `less` package since you want to load them raw, you will also need to reference them manually as Meteor will ignore the less once you remove the `less` package.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the server-side less package over the client-side lessjs library? Also, if I move my current less files to client-side, will I then have loading order issues (i seem to remember having these issues a while back when they were being loaded before the less files in a Bootstrap package)?

Comment: yes, there's a big advantage to using server-side less and that's performance. less.js is a huge library and you typically don't want that loaded in a production site.

Comment: @JoePrivett You would also run into the issues you're describing besides performance (which is a very noticable loss) as CSS will be loaded last as opposed to first (and still needs compiling to your preference). Because its loaded last I think it would override bootstrap.